# cAdvisor not rendering UI on a remote IP Address

Tags: ubuntu, cadvisor

I have a VPS(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) where I have installed cAdvisor using the standard command as mentioned in the documentation -

```
sudo docker run   --volume=/:/rootfs:ro   --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw   --volume=/sys:/sys:ro   --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro   --publish=2020:2020   --detach=true   --name=cadvisor   google/cadvisor:latest --logtostderr
```

Doing a `docker ps` shows a container with name cAdvisor up and running.

Here are the syslogs -

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.163095600Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/d7ea5b23a9adef46512d0e6558705b67abf76ca7e659b876e96b39c2671d9d4e/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.164485455Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/d7ea5b23a9adef46512d0e6558705b67abf76ca7e659b876e96b39c2671d9d4e/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.179509677Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/324eff724ff4dc37b560d69de4b9d55baf3ee2d8a563697e14d345e0e7ca5d0e/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.180811473Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/324eff724ff4dc37b560d69de4b9d55baf3ee2d8a563697e14d345e0e7ca5d0e/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.187200355Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/1ca28d92213568732efde8a935ea935b8a82d235e2585751f3c60d191e9d5557/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.188571105Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/1ca28d92213568732efde8a935ea935b8a82d235e2585751f3c60d191e9d5557/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.192465837Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/99b3e78062f67c5b5dabdddab4091449e4b81b1ad067426618b4dcbfec2e2157/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.193462558Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/99b3e78062f67c5b5dabdddab4091449e4b81b1ad067426618b4dcbfec2e2157/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.195544729Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/85df2cf4dde10d08cd598485975b330cdd00d04c9426616f61e28729e74f8e56/json"
Mar 19 11:56:28 localhost docker[6250]: time="2016-03-19T11:56:28.196908541Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/85df2cf4dde10d08cd598485975b330cdd00d04c9426616f61e28729e74f8e56/json"
```

Everything going fine up until now.

1. I open the Address in browser, no response.
2. I do a ssh tunnel and map 2020 of remote to my 2020 of local machine and open `localhost:2020` no response.
3. The IP Address of the container running cAdvisor is `172.17.0.9` doing an `nc -vz 172.17.0.9 2020` returns connection refused.

   172.17.0.9: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
   (UNKNOWN) [172.17.0.9] 2020 (?) : Connection refused

Any thoughts on whats gone wrong?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `--publish=2020:2020` is just the option for Docker container, which means it ports the container's 2020 to VM's 2020.

But inside the container, the `cadvisor` program is default listening to `8080`, not `2020`.

So, you should add `cadvisor` cmd option: `--port=2020`
https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs%2Fruntime_options.md

The whole cmd looks like this:

```
sudo docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --publish=2020:2020 \
  --detach=true \
  --name=cadvisor \
  google/cadvisor:latest \
  --logtostderr \
  --port=2020
```